# Finding image file of mounted ISO

Tags: windows, powershell, disk-image

When I mount an ISO file like `C:\temp\demo.iso` by double clicking it on Windows 10 and/or Windows Server (or `Mount-DiskImage` powershell command) I can see the new disk (in this case it returned a new drive `I:`):

```
Get-Volume I | fc

class CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Volume
{
  ObjectId = {1}\\HOST01\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\WSP_Volume.ObjectId="{de774a20-4e16-11e8-ad1
  e-806e6f6e6963}:VO:\\?\Volume{354097cd-6bd5-11e7-a5d9-aaaaa99b2b5d}\"
  PassThroughClass =
  PassThroughIds =
  PassThroughNamespace =
  PassThroughServer =
  UniqueId = \\?\Volume{354097cd-6bd5-11e7-a5d9-aaaaa99b2b5d}\
  AllocationUnitSize = 2048
  DedupMode = NotAvailable
  DriveLetter = I
  DriveType = CD-ROM
  FileSystem = CDFS
  FileSystemLabel = 20190306-134242
  FileSystemType = Unknown
  HealthStatus = Healthy
  OperationalStatus = OK
  Path = \\?\Volume{354097cd-6bd5-11e7-a5d9-aaaaa99b2b5d}\
  Size = 2136489984
  SizeRemaining = 0
  PSComputerName =
}
```

But I can't see what the image source file path (the `c:\temp\demo.iso`) for that disk was. `mount-diskimage` returns this information as a result object, but where can I get it after the fact or when mounted with explorer? I need to script that with powershell.

Comment: What value in the example above are you expecting to see? When you say image source file, what exactly do you want it to tell you? the iso filename you mounted?

Comment: Added an example in the question @Narzard

Comment: I think you want: `Get-Volume -DriveLetter I | Get-DiskImage`

Comment: @Narzard get-diskimage in this case returns nothing, I guess it only works with imagepath, it can't extract that from the Volume object. But basically that would be a good cmdlet if it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the DevicePath then

```
Get-DiskImage -DevicePath \\.\CDROM0
```

If you only know the Drive letter try (you need to remove the end '\' from path)

```
Get-Volume -DriveLetter I  | % { Get-DiskImage -DevicePath $($_.Path -replace "\\$")}
```

Sample result:

```
Attached          : True
DevicePath        : \\.\CDROM1
FileSize          : 2494107648
ImagePath         : C:\temp\demo.iso
LogicalSectorSize : 2048
...
```

Comment: Cool, `get-diskimage -devicepath` works, it returns in an `ImagePath` property the path I need.

Comment: And then `Dismount-DiskImage -DevicePath \\.\CDROM0` great.